# Filebeats, get folder name as part of tag

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Let's say I have a path something like this:

```
  paths:
     - /var/log/webapp/*.log*
     - /var/log/webapp/*app*.log*
  document_type: webapp
```

How would I change this to name the document type based off of the folder name under /var/log/*/ automatically to be whatever is in the *?

Example:

/var/log/app/* -- produces app logs

/var/log/alpha/* --produces alpha logs

/var/log//beta/* -- produces beta logs

/var/log/delta/* -- produces delta logs.

Is it possible to do this with beats, or do I need to handle this on the logstash side using grok or a ruby filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways you could do this:

The first is to just create different prospectors in your Filebeat configuration, which are folder specific to a log type. This is the officially recommended way to do this.

OR

If you want to use one wide prospector and avoid the builtin solution for your problem, use logstash. Filebeat gives you a field which has the path of the origin file, I think its called `file`. You could grok it like:

```
file => "/var/log/%{WORD:log_type}/%{GREEDYDATA}"
```

The issue that I have experienced here is that the type set by Filebeat seems resistant to change by Logstash, not sure how this works, but it was certainly a headache when I tried it.